# Move Search Bar - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the search bar next to the logo on our website but not having any luck.

My theme is based on magento luma.

I have the below code

```
<move element="block.search" destination="header.wrapper" after="logo" />
```

inside of

```
mytheme/theme/layout/default.xml
```

but the changes aren't being reflected.

[image]

I have also tried the below code.

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Comment: That code kind of works, but now it has disappeared and isn't showing up under right click > inspect on chrome??

Comment: my destination path was wrong as well: mytheme/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml - also had to apply css - float: left; to 'block-search' class.

Answer (score 1):

Name of destination container is "header-wrapper" and you have written "header.wrapper", for this reason your code is not working.

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Use above code, it will work fine.